# Sum row with next row value and grab next value in other column for the date selected

Tags: powerbi, dax, row, calculation

Let's say I have this data:

```
         Earn     Earn Cum.
13-Apr       -        -   
14-Apr      48        48 
15-Apr     257       305 
16-Apr     518       823 
17-Apr     489     1,312 
18-Apr     837     2,149 
19-Apr   1,005     3,154 
20-Apr   1,021     4,175 
21-Apr   1,463     5,638 
22-Apr   2,630     8,268 
23-Apr   2,993    11,261 
24-Apr   3,354    14,615 
25-Apr   4,332    18,947 
26-Apr   4,885    23,832 
27-Apr   4,514    28,346 
28-Apr   4,356    32,702 
29-Apr   4,824    37,526 
30-Apr   7,082    44,608 
1-May    6,091    50,699 
2-May    1,407    52,106
```

When a date is selected in a dropdown slicer for example: 1-May I'd like to sum the rows 1-May with the next row 2-May for the column **Earn** and grab the next value 52,106 for the column **Earn Cum.**. The result should be:

```
1-May    7,498    52,106
```

Another example: if the date selected was 30-Apr the result must be:

```
30-Apr  13,173    50,699
```

I'm scratching my head trying to do this using a measure in Power BI.

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to write a couple measures?

Comment: Yes... I'd like to put this in a measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll call your table "Data".

Create a measure:

```
Next Earn =
VAR Current_Date = MAX ( Data[Date] )
VAR Next_Date = Current_Date + 1
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Data[Earn] ),
        Data[Date] = Current_Date || Data[Date] = Next_Date
    )
```

Create another measure:

```
Next Cum Earn = 
VAR Current_Date =  MAX ( Data[Date] )
VAR Next_Date = Current_Date + 1
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[Earn Cum] ), Data[Date] = Next_Date )
```

Result:

[image]

Note: the code assumes that your dates are sequential (no gaps). If they have gaps, things are a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'll try it... Could you also shed some light here? stackoverflow.com/q/56658634/114029

Comment: RADO... this problem also applies to that sample. `.pbix` I shared in the other question. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r7kiIkwgHnI5GUssJ6KlXBAoeDRISEuC. All filters applied.
I added `Next Earn` measure and it's moving the Earn value one row above. 14-Apr has value 48 and this value is being moved to 13-Apr and somewhat it's changing all the values. It should just sum the last value while keeping the values in their respective dates. Instead of letting the user select the cutting date, this date is set in a new table in the .pbix. Let's call it `Cut date`.

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri - I am having hard time understanding your comment

Comment: I'll upload a different testing .pbix so that you can play with it.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OG7keqhdvDUDYkFQFMHyxcpi9Zi6Pn3d see that it's not working as expected. I'll update the question and add a printscreen.

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri - [Next Earn] measure seems to be working as you requested (results are matching your desired outcome). [Next Cum Earn] measure won't work, because you've changed the data (Earn Cum in your question is a column, and I don't see it in the pbix data). If you need a **measure for cumulative earnings**, that's a different question :)

Comment: You're right... this makes for a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56677415/114029

Answer (score 1):

It will help to have access to date intelligence, so create a date table if you don't have one already.  The following dax sets up a small table that just barely covers the sample data in your example.

```
Date = CALENDAR(Date(2019,4,10),Date(2019,5,5))
```

Create a relationship between the Dates in your table and the new Date dimension.  Add a slicer to your visuals using the Date dimension.

We can use IF and ISFILTERED to check if filtering is being done.  If we aren't filtering on `Date` then we get the normal table behavior.  If we are, we'll see our modified result.

```
Earn _ Alt = 
var tomorrow = CALCULATE (
    SUM(Table1[Earn]),
    dateadd('Table1'[Date], 1, DAY)
 )

return Sum(Table1[Earn]) + IF(ISFILTERED`('Date'[Date]),tomorrow,0)`
```

and

```
Earn Cum. _ Alt = IF(ISFILTERED('Date'[Date]),
CALCULATE (
    SUM(Table1[Earn Cum.]),
    dateadd('Table1'[Date], 1, DAY)
 ),
SUM(Table1[Earn Cum.]))
```

Results:

-Unfiltered-
[image]

-Filtered-
[image]

Comment: Awesome! Can you shed some light here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56658634/114029