# Manipulating last two rows if there's data based on a Cut date

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, date-arithmetic, measure

This question is a slightly varied version of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56656980/114029)...

Now I'm using `Measures` instead of `Calculated columns` and the date is static instead of having it based on a dropdown list.

Here's the Power BI test `.pbix` file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OG7keqhdvDUDYkFQFMHyxcpi9Zi6Pn3d

This printscreen describes what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Basically the date in `P6 Update` table is used as a ***cut date*** and will be fixed\static. It's imported from an Excel sheet where the user can customize it however they want.

Here's what should happen when a matching row in Test data table is found for `P6 Update` date:

- column `Earned Daily` - must have its value summed with the next row if there's one;
- column `Earned Cum` - must grab the next row's value;
- all the previous rows should remain intact, that is, their values won't change;
- all subsequent rows must have their values assigned 0.

So for example:

If `P6 Update` is **1-May-2018**, this is the expected result:

```
1-May    7,498    52,106
2-May        0         0
```

If `P6 Update` is **30-Apr-2018**, this is the expected result:

```
30-Apr  13,173    50,699
1-May        0         0
2-May        0         0
```

If `P6 Update` is **29-Apr-2018**, this is the expected result:

```
29-Apr  11,906    44,608
30-Apr       0         0
1-May        0         0
2-May        0         0
```

and so on...

Hope this makes sense.

This is easier in Excel, but trying to do this in Power BI is making me go nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will ignore previously asked related questions and start from scratch.

First, create a measure:

```
Current Earn = 
CALCULATE (
        SUM( 'Test data'[Value]),
        'Test data'[Act Rem] = "Actual Units",
        'Test data'[Type] = "Current"
    )
```

This measure will be used in other measures, to save you from typing all these conditions ("Actual Units" and "Current") again and again. It's a great practice to re-use measures in other measures - saves work, makes code cleaner and easier to refactor.

Create another measure:

```
Cut Date = SELECTEDVALUE('P6 Update'[Date])
```

We will use this measure whenever we need a cut off date. Please note that it does not have to be hard-coded - if P6 table contains a list of dates, you can create a pull-down slicer from the dates, and can choose the cut-off date dynamically. The formula will work properly.

Create third measure:

```
Next Earn =
VAR Cut_Date = [Cut Date]
VAR Current_Date = MAX ( 'Test data'[Date] )
VAR Next_Date = Current_Date + 1
VAR Current_Earn = [Current Earn]
VAR Next_Earn = CALCULATE ( [Current Earn], 'Test data'[Date] = Next_Date )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE,
        Current_Date < Cut_Date, Current_Earn,
        Current_Date = Cut_Date, Current_Earn + Next_Earn,
        BLANK ()
    )
```

I am not sure if "Next Earn" is a good name for it, hopefully you will find a more intuitive name. The way it works: we save all necessary inputs into variables, and then use SWITCH function to define the results. Hopefully it's self-explanatory. (Note: if you need 0 above Cut Date, replace BLANK() with 0).

Finally, we define a measure for cumulative earn. It does not require any special logic, because previous measure takes care of it properly:

```
Cum Earn = 
VAR Current_Date = MAX('Test data'[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Next Earn],
    FILTER(ALL('Test data'[Date]), 'Test data'[Date] <= Current_Date))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Incredible! Looking at the code you wrote it looks so simple... :) Lots to learn regarding DAX. It's way powerful than good old Excel.

Comment: I agree. DAX is amazing; productivity gain vs Excel is like 100x, if you know what you are doing. I recommend you this resource: https://www.sqlbi.com/ These guys are the best experts I know of. Read their book ("Definitive guide to DAX"), and take online class ("Mastering DAX"). Very productive way to build the foundation.

Comment: To make this a killer solution... they could add `debugging` so that we could go step by step\row by row and check what's going on. Just like we have in Visual Studio. That would be paradise.

Comment: You can get a better visibility into the code by using tools like DAX studio.

Comment: Hey RADO... could you shed some light here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59584790/114029 ... I tried a lot of formulas' variations but I can't get the 1st value fixed. I do understand the problem, that is, Export table only has rows for those 3 dates.

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri - as it's written, the question is hard to understand. It'd be great if you provide a data model diagram, data samples and a example to workout (or, a pbix file that allows to reproduce the problem and test a solution).

Comment: I put together a `Sample.pbix` with an annotated printscreen to describe what I'm trying to achieve. The problem is that `Export` table has no data for all the dates in `Planning`. You can download the sample here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zxS_2VE9_0JEMXvsg9Dq196BK552RbNo?usp=sharing